# Where do I download Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, download, adt

Where are you supposed to download the Eclipse ADT now that it has been replaced by Android Studio and Google's Android Developer download page at http://developer.android.com/sdk/ doesn't provide it for download anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://tools.android.com/download Here is a link I found on google you can get the binary or build it yourself.